# How to read numbers from a file and measure the time it takes?

Tags: c, file

I have a text file called 10.text that contains 10 large numbers. I want to read those numbers and store them in an array of size 10. Then i want to print out these nmbers and the time it takes to read the file.

Here is my attempt:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


int i;
clock_t start, end;
double cpu_time_used;
double TimeOfReadingFile;
FILE *myFile;
int readarr10[10];


start = clock();
myFile=fopen("10.txt" ,"r");


printf("SIZE 10\n");
printf("----------------\n");
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    fscanf(myFile, "%d", &readarr10[i]);
end = clock();


 for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
            printf("%d  ",readarr10[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
TimeOfReadingFile=cpu_time_used*pow(10, 9);
printf("time for reading the 10 file: %f\n",TimeOfReadingFile);

return 0;}
```

the problem is that when i run it i get zeros for all thr numbers and a zero for the time.
This code is part of a project i am working on and i cannot continue if i dont get it right!

Comment: Why are you multiplying the elapsed time with one billion? That might become a *very* large number!

Comment: It is actually declared in my code, i just forgot to copy and paste it in the question. I fixed that anyway!

Comment: When things go wrong, one normally realize that return values from input functions should not be ignored. You should control that `myFile` is not `NULL` and that all `fscanf` call actually return 1.

Comment: The time calculated is in seconds, I want it in nanosecs.

Comment: No the time isn't in seconds. `((double) end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is the elapsed time in seconds.

Comment: Yes! i want the elapsed time in nanosecs!

Comment: So multiply the result of `((double) end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` with `1000000000`? Did you just forget the division with `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`? And don't use `pow`, the result might not be *exactly* one billion (though probably it is).

Comment: No that's a ***comment!***

Comment: I fixed it. But i am still getting zeroes!

Comment: Then the final resort for you is to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

Reading 10 numbers can be below the definition of `clock`. On my BSD system on a virtual machine, I had to loop more than 1000 times to begin to see something. With a loop of 1000000 times (read 10 integers, rewind file) I get (more or less 2.5 micro sec for the operation. If I include the fopen/fclose in the loop, I end at 24 micro sec.

I think (but I must acknowledge that I am not sure of it), that a rewind on a small FILE* only resets the file pointer but does not read again any sector from the disk. On the other hand, reading 10 integers (one single disk operation) should be short behind opening and closing a file.

So my conclusion is (on my system):

- file access: more or less 20 micro seconds
- decoding 10 integer: more of less 2 micro seconds.

I have a not too fast disk and the overhead on running a VirtualBox machine, so on high speed computers, times could even be smaller. So on one single iteration it is no surprise that `end == start`.

Comment: Note also that clock() measures CPU time (except on Windows), while usually you care about the total time spent. For file reading most of the time could be spent fetching data from the disk, not executing CPU instructions. (Then again, to measure file i/o, there are many more things to consider, most importantly that the performance depends entirely on whether the file resides in the kernel memory cache or not)

Comment: ..and whether it's cached in the disk drive buffers, or quickly available from an SSD, or..whatever;)